# How do I fix an “Invalid license data. Reinstall is required.” error in Visual Shell Express (Isolated) 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shell

So I have recently instealled Visual Shell Express (Isolated) 2010 in Windows 7.
The problem is, every time I open it, it says, Invalid License Data.  Reinstall Required.
I saw this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673275/how-do-i-fix-an-invalid-license-data-reinstall-is-required-error-in-visual-c
It looks like an answer to my question, but the subinacl command line tool doesn't work on Windows 7.

Are there any other ways to replicate the fix on windows 7 without the command line tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error when attempting to install and run the free Visual Studio 2010 Shell alongside a licensed copy of Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

As described [in the thread you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673275/how-do-i-fix-an-invalid-license-data-reinstall-is-required-error-in-visual-c), the issue appears to involve a conflict with how the Visual Studio installers manage updates to the Windows Registry key settings associated with software licensing.

In my case, simply uninstalling and re-installing the Visual Studio 2010 Shell did not resolve my issue.  However, I was able to resolve my issue without making any manual changes to the Windows Registry by installing [SQL Server Data Tools 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014), which is also free and includes the Visual Studio 2010 Shell.